# Share not showing up in PROFILE_ID/feed, though realtime notification sent

Tags: facebook-graph-api, real-time

I have  a realtime handler setup for an app, and it gets a notification of change in a user's feed (changed_fields': ['feed']) due to a Share of someone else's public Wall Photo.  However, when I look at the https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/feed endpoint with a read_stream-authorized token, the change is not present.

Is there another way to access this share?